# How to batch rename multiple folders in a directory to lowercase using only command prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, command-prompt

I am organizing my music folder and I would like to rename all folders within my music folder so that every character in the folder name is in lowercase, without changing anything else.

Is there a way I can do this with the Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "alphabet=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%targetdir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "name1=%%a"
 SET "name2=%%a"
 CALL :subsren
)

GOTO :EOF

:subsren
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%s IN (%alphabet%) DO SET "name2=!name2:%%s=%%s!"
endlocal&SET "name2=%name2%"
if "%name1%" neq "%name2%" ECHO(REN "%targetdir%\%name1%" "%name2%"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `targetdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Grab each filename and assign it to `name1` and `name2`, then call subroutine `:subsren`

Replace each letter in `name2` with its lowercse equivalent, then use the standard parsing trick to export the modified `name2` outside of the `setlocal/endlocal` bracket.

rename if `name2` is different from `name1` and all done!